# Can I use Angular 6 without Webpack?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I want to compile my angular 6 codes and pack them myself.

Can I use Angular 6 without Webpack?

And Does packing `.html` and `.css` into a `.js` **WebPack's** Job or **Angular CLI's** Job??

Comment: angular cli uses webpack internally

Comment: just for curiosity, may I know Why you don't want to use Webpack

Comment: @AnkitKumar because I don't want to embed my html files in `main.js` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Webpack** is a JavaScript module bundler. **Angular cli** uses it to pack and build the Angular app.

If you want to use Angular cli then you're stuck with **Webpack** for now.

Otherwise if you create your own architecture to bundle and build your app (which is harder) then you can use other Javascript module bundlers such as [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en) and [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Webpack is a powerful module bundler. A bundle is a JavaScript file that incorporates assets that belong together and should be served to the client in a response to a single file request. A bundle can include JavaScript, CSS styles, HTML, and almost any other kind of file.

Webpack roams over your application source code, looking for import statements, building a dependency graph, and emitting one or more bundles. With plugins and rules, Webpack can preprocess and minify different non-JavaScript files such as TypeScript, SASS, and LESS files.